# Recursive DFS shortest path implementation not working as expected

Tags: python, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

For a university assignment we have to implement a recursive naive shortest path algorithm for a weighted graph. It should check all the routes, and from that we can find the shortest.

We have been working on a Python script for a lot of time now, but we cannot get it to work properly. This is what we have now:

```
import numpy as np
global paths
paths = []

class Path:
        def __init__(self):
            self.NodeArray = [];
            self.Weight = 0;


def vindpaden(start,end,pad):
    pad.NodeArray.append(start)
    print "path so far: " + str(pad.NodeArray)
    global paths
    print "Start:" + str(start) + ", " + "end: " + str(end)
    if start == end:
        print "returning"
        paths.append(pad)
    else:
        for j in range(len(graph)):
            if (j not in pad.NodeArray) and graph[start][j] != -1:
                newpaths = vindpaden(j,end,pad)

graph = np.loadtxt("input2.txt")
graph = graph.astype(int)

start = 0
end = 1

path = Path()
vindpaden(start,end,path)

print "###### results:"
for p in paths:
    print "length: " + str(p.Weight) + ", path: " + str(p.NodeArray)
```

We are using an adjacency matrix as input. For testing, we are using the simple testing graph:

[image: graph]

With the following adjacency matrix (where -1 means no connection):

```
-1 -1  1 -1
 3 -3 -1 -1
 2  2 -1  1
-1  2 -1 -1
```

**This results in the following output:**

```
path so far: [0]
Start:0, end: 1
path so far: [0, 2]
Start:2, end: 1
path so far: [0, 2, 1]
Start:1, end: 1
returning
path so far: [0, 2, 1, 3]
Start:3, end: 1
######
length: 0, path: [0, 2, 1, 3]
```

So you can see it finds a path from point 0 to point 1 via 2, after that it should add the path [0,2,1] to the array paths and continue looking for paths from point 2. Instead, it return the (incorrect) path [0,2,1,3]. In the end, the only path in the array paths is [0,2,1,3], which is also strange.

**This is what we expect the output to be:**

```
path so far: [0]
Start:0, end: 1
path so far: [0, 2]
Start:2, end: 1
path so far: [0, 2, 1]
Start:1, end: 1
returning
path so far: [0, 2, 3]
Start:3, end: 1
path so far: [0 ,2, 3, 1]
Start:1, end: 1
returning
######
length: 0, path: [0, 2, 1]
length: 0, path: [0, 2, 3, 1]
```

Please note that we are not using the property *weight* at this moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you are only ever create a single instance of `Path()`, which results in that instance's `NodeArray` getting corrupted.  What I think is happens is as follows:

- You get to the point where the `NodeArray` contains `[0, 2, 1]`.
- The function detects that it has reached the target, and thus goes back to the most recent node to check the rest of the potential paths.
- Going from node `2`, the next node after `1` is `3`, so `3` is added to the `NodeArray` list.  Because the list hasn't been cleared, the new node (`3`) is just added to the end, resulting in `[0, 2, 1, 3`].
- Now, because `1` is already in your current `NodeArray`, the if statement `if (j not in pad.NodeArray) and graph[start][j] != -1:` fails and the function stops.

I think what you need to do is to create a new `Path()` every time you call `vindpaden()`, and copy the current `Path`'s `NodeArray` into the new `Path`.

Comment: I found the problem, and it is indeed exactly like you say. :) I solved it by passing deepcopy(pad), instead of pad.

I was expecting Python to pass-by-value, but after reading up on it it seems Python uses it's own tricks for passing variables.